# Move an element at the beginning of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have array format like this

```js
response = {
  "data": [{
      "districts": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "sikkim district",
        "statistics": [{
          "food saftey": 2,
          "food ": 2,
          "air pollution": 0
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      "districts": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bhojpur",
        "statistics": [{
          "food saftey": 1,
          "food ": 1,
          "air pollution": 1
        }]
      }]
    }
  ],

}
```

and the required format is

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "district": "sikkim district",
            "food saftey": 2,
            "food ": 2,
            "air pollution": 0
        },
        {
             "district": "Bhojpur",
             "food saftey": 1,
             "food ": 1,
             "air pollution": 1
        },
        
    ],
 
}
```

The array format is in dynamic which keeps changing except the district 
and the district has to be at the beginning of the array.

Comment: What you have here is an array with one object in it and this object has 3 `data` properties which makes it invalid (property names must be unique). Additionally, the order in which you declare the properties in the object doesn't matter.

Comment: There are more problems with the validity of your json - like missing `,` between the properties and a space in the `Bal Vivah` property name.

Comment: Your format should be something like [{districts: "East District","Bal Vivah": 1,"Type": 0},{"districts": "West District","Bal Vivah": 1,"Type": 0},...]

Comment: i will add the backend response

Comment: This json is not valid and even if it were, no, you can't guarantee order on object properties. You can use Map instead.

Comment: can you check now

Comment: Your data from the server and the data you require are a lot different. You need to covert the data structure (either in the server or when it gets to the client) before you use it in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is put the property you know first in a column array and then get the other properties and loop over using the order in the column array.

Something like this:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ehb7z)

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = [{
      "Bal Vivah": 1,
      "Type": 0,
      "districts": "East District"
    },
    {
      "Bal Vivah": 1,
      "Type": 0,
      "districts": "West District"
    },
    {
      "Bal Vivah": 1,
      "Type": 0,
      "districts": "North District"
    }
  ]

  columns: string[] = ["districts"];

  constructor() {
    // get the columns from the data
    if (this.data) {
      var dataObject = this.data[0];
      for (var property in dataObject) {
        if (property != "districts" && dataObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          this.columns.push(property);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let column of columns">
      <th>{{column}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let columnData of data">
      <tr *ngFor="let column of columns">
        <td>
          {{columnData[column]| json}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: I changed your data to be valid json.